# Dynamically add column names to data.table when aggregating

Tags: r, data.table

I know we can dynamically add column names when creating columns by reference (using `:=`), as described e.g. here: [Dynamic column names in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745169/dynamic-column-names-in-data-table-r).

However, I'm looking to dynamically add column names when we aggregate. Can you help with this?

```
test_dtb <- data.table(a = sample(1:100, 100), b = sample(1:100, 100), id = rep(1:10, 10))
m = "blah"
test_dtb[ , list((m) = mean(b)), by = id]
```

The error I get is

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "test_dtb[ , list((m) =
```

Comment: [Maybe this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37143023/2204410)

Comment: I'm programmatically creating the m variable and its length can vary from 1 to 5. I think it would be hard to define which index to setnames from.

Comment: What about `m = c("blah", "foo");test_dtb[,setNames(list(mean(b),median(b)), m),by = id]`?

Comment: `test_dtb[,eval(m):=mean(b),by = id]` ?

Comment: works with multiple values also: `m = c("blah", "foo"); test_dtb[,eval(m):=list(mean(b),median(b)),by = id,verbose=TRUE]` gives:        `a   b id blah  foo` columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by lukeA, `setNames` can be used:

```
m <- c("blah", "foo")
test_dtb[ , setNames(list(mean(b), median(b)), m), by = id]
```

Answer (score -2):

## Just make sure data.table knows "m" is not a variable name.

## Parentheses or "c"  will do.

```
test_dtb[, (m)  := mean(b),by = id]
test_dtb[, c(m) := mean(b),by = id]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, its while I'm aggregating. The answers in the comments help with that.

Comment: Woops! My mistake. In this case, the solution suggested by  lukeA is an excellent one.